# WriteFile() Error 3758100489 with Usb Device

Tags: windows, api, x86

I have a project to communicate with a usb device using usb bus.
The device has its own driver and a communication protokol Guid .
In its guid there is this senetence :"After USB driver is installed any program can communicate with the device by using ‘CreateFile’,
‘ReadFile’ and ‘WriteFile’, common Windows system functions."
So I followed the instructions and the Creatfile() function works very well.
My problem is with Writefile()and ReadFile functions.
It shows always this Error 3758100489 :
In the guid book there is this note:All messages use Intel style byte ordering where fields larger than one byte are stored in memory so
that the least significant part is in lowest address.
So i tried to use functions to convert to littel Endien too 
I tried to use overlapped parameter in Creatfile() and Writefile() but still have the same problem.
i tried to use many forms of message packet with help from the guid too

Can anyone help me ? thank you very much

P.s
USB path is right 100%

Answer (score 1):

Your error code in hex is `0xE0001009`. The USB device should be locked before you can perform the operation. I am not completely sure and can't test it, but I think you would need this function [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) to lock the volume first.

In [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) documentation, it's mentioned

A write on a disk handle will succeed if one of the following conditions is true:

- The sectors to be written to do not fall within a volume's extents.
- The sectors to be written to fall within a mounted volume, but you
  have explicitly locked or dismounted the volume by using
  FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME or FSCTL_DISMOUNT_VOLUME.

This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364575(v=vs.85).aspx) could help in making the call for locking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get more info about `3758100489`.

See [Retrieving the Last-Error Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/retrieving-the-last-error-code) or try to build and run the following program which should show you a human readable description of error `3758100489`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

void main()
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    //DWORD dw = GetLastError();
    DWORD dw = 3758100489; 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) ); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("failed with error %d: %s"), 
         dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Comment: i have tried but it failed with error -536866807:null